# wordpress изображения для разных устройств

Tags: wordpress

Используется wordpress + bootstrap 4 
Есть 2 варианта изображений, 1 для desktopa и 1 для mobile.
Шаблон адаптивный. Вставляет как html код в страницу.
 
Так вот вопрос в том как загружать только нужное изображение? 
 
Управляю отображение таким образом.

```
<div>
  <img class="m" src="URL" alt="">
  <img class="d" src="URL" alt="">
</div>

.m {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 540px) {
  .d {
    display: none;
  }

  .m {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Возможно я вообще неправильно подхожу к реализации и есть более правильные решения. Может есть какие то wordpress плагины или в bootstrap что то есть.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и так, как вы написали, но все это - пустая трата времени. WordPress в последних версиях использует srcset для адаптации изображений на сайте. Этот подход обеспечивает создание и перечисление нескольких размеров изображений, а браузер выбирает уже тот размер, который наилучшим образом подходит к текущему размеру экрана. Например:

```
<img width="400" height="400" src="//test.kagg.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/779366a5-4648-386d-a3e1-c3d63b994237-400x400.jpg" class="attachment-shop_catalog size-shop_catalog wp-post-image" alt="" srcset="//test.kagg.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/779366a5-4648-386d-a3e1-c3d63b994237-400x400.jpg 400w, //test.kagg.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/779366a5-4648-386d-a3e1-c3d63b994237-150x150.jpg 150w, //test.kagg.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/779366a5-4648-386d-a3e1-c3d63b994237-157x157.jpg 157w, //test.kagg.eu/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/779366a5-4648-386d-a3e1-c3d63b994237-100x100.jpg 100w" sizes="(max-width: 767px) 89vw, (max-width: 1000px) 54vw, (max-width: 1071px) 543px, 580px">
```

Выводите картинки стандартными средствами WordPress, и вы получите адаптивность картинок на сайте.

Comment: Спасибо. Жаль что с поддержкой плохо у этого атрибут .

Comment: С чего вы это взяли? Can I use почитали? Посмотрите страницу http://test.kagg.eu/shop/ , в том числе в IE и Edge.

Comment: @Dima см http://caniuse.com/#search=srcset Кстати srcset в ВП ещё и автоматом "выравнивает" протокол, если сайт доступен по разным.

Comment: Ну и я о том же. На сарае у бабки Пелагеи ещё не то написано. Вы на реальную страницу, напичканную srcset посмотрите. Я же вам ссылку дал.

Comment: Смотрел здесь. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img

Раньше меня этот ресурс не подводил, извините ошибся.

Comment: Я не совсем понял последний комментарий, но вот по факту тестовая страница работает во всех браузерах. И есть у меня подозрение, что если бы это было не так, команда WordPress не стала бы применять srcset. А появился этот атрибут недавно в WP.

Comment: @KAGGDesign работает  в тех, которые поддерживают. Старые браузеры, конечно не поддерживают, тк не знают о нём. Но это либо сильно старые, либо какие-то экзотические. Я выше дал ссылку кто и как поддерживает.

Comment: @SeVlad ааа, это ж ты дал ссылку, а я и не заметил. Но весь прикол в том, что там ерунда написана в can I use. Я только что проверил свою тестовую страницу во всем современном

Comment: @KAGGDesign а чего ерунда-то? Там и написано, что всё своевременное поддерживает. С каких версий какой браузер.

Comment: @SeVlad там же IE и Edge красным

Comment: Там эдж 16й зелёный. (Эджа у меня нет вообще, а как будет возможность - посмотрю что реально в ИЕ.грузится)

Comment: @SeVlad да, точно. Не туда глянул) Но можешь не проверять. У меня все есть. И только что проверил. Везде работает страница, как часы.

Comment: Спасибо, действительно работает и в ie 11 и в android, жаль на ios 6/7 не могу проверить, но смеют предположить что и там будет все работать.

Comment: Ну ИЕ вё же относительно древний и когда там поддержка его кончилась, так что может и не поддерживаться, а то, что ты видишь.. ну может и не srcset :) или кеш или ещё что.. Но не буду утверждать - надо самому проверить.

Comment: Я только что проверил на последнем MacBook Pro со Sierra. Все ок

Comment: @SeVlad ты думаешь, я в ослике в код не заглянул? Зряяя )))

Comment: :) нет оснований не верить, но я такие вещи смотрю и на проксе - это даже более достоверно, чем код в браузера. Просто сейчас не могу посмотреть. А в целом я абсолютно согласен, что это хороший вариант. (я ж плюсанул ;)) Лучше чем через стили. Но может хуже, чем через php. Но это и сложнее и тоже зависит от ситуации.